# SDN Neo4j Cypher case insensitive query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a following Spring Data Neo4j(3.4.0.RELEASE) entity with an `indexed` property `name`:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Decision {

    @Indexed
    private String name;
    ....
```

I need to implement case-insensitive search by `name` property.

In my `DecisionRepository` I have created a following method:

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE d.name =~ '(?i){name}' RETURN d")
Decision findByNameIgnoreCase(@Param("name") String name);
```

but after execution I'm getting a following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Illegal repetition near index 3
(?i){name}
   ^; nested exception is java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 3
(?i){name}
   ^
```

How to implement correct case-insensitive search over name property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a bit tricky, but you can do this using this query in annotation I guess:

```
MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE LOWER(d.name) = LOWER({name}) RETURN d
```

If you set both of your names (parameter and value) to lower, case doesn't matter.

To do exactly what you want (regex matching), you have to use //:

```
MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE d.name =~ /(?i){name}/ RETURN d
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, with `LOWER` function it works like a charm !